# Identify where-used table for a field of SAP ERP transaction

Tags: sap-erp

I've managed to identify the table from an attribute in SAP Netweaver ERP.
For example, *Order Number* (AUFNR) comes from table AUFK, and my question is: where do attributes like *Material description* (MATXT) come from?

[image]

I can't found this info via SAP user interface (from the little I know) and when I search on the internet for the structure, this attribute is also unidentifiable.
I post this question because I need to extract data to SQL Server tables, and I can't seem to find the source, via SAP user interface or on the internet. 
 This might be probably a conceptual question about data organization in SAP.

Answer (score 1):

The naming of this field (**CO_XXXXX**) unequivocally points out that this field relates to CO (Controlling) module, which should have been suggest you the proper direction.
The most probable tables this field can relate to are **COCH** and **COCHP**. 
However, this fieldname is widely used in *Plant Maintenance Notifications* (PM-WOC-MN) as well.
Full list of structures and tables where it is used can be obtained in `DD03L` table. Query by field `FIELDNAME`, for example, like this, should give you the thing

```
SELECT *
  INTO TABLE @DATA(result)
  FROM dd03l As d3
  JOIN dd02l AS d2
    ON d3~tabname = d2~tabname
 WHERE d3~fieldname = 'MATXT'
   AND d2~tabclass = 'TRANSP'. << if you want to exclude structures
```

P.S. Your screenshot is almost unreadable.

**Update:**

1. SAP has [plenty of modules](http://sapoverview.blogspot.ru/2012/10/sap-modules-overview.html)  and their consideration is out of the scope of your question.
2. Why they should? It is rhetorical question.
3. If you are nor ABAPer, you can simply use 'MATXT' as search predicate in SE11/SE16/SE16n for table `DD03L`.

`F1` -> `Technical Info` command should help in finding used structures in **most**  cases, but not in 100% of cases. To identify what tables are used in a transaction is almost *impossible* without such tools as Debugger, Traces and without ABAP experience.

Comment: Hi, i'm a BI consultant, SAP newbie, and i need to select and extract SAP tables to SQL Server.
1) OK, how many modules are there and what their prefixes?
2) So why aren't these tables identified on SAP user interface (print screen) ?
3) Where can i run this SAP query?
If my client gives me a transaction (or a program), what is the best way to see all the used structures with their attributes, and the table for each attribute? For example, I've searched for structure IOHEADER used in TRAN COOIS and on the internet, and only some attributes have a table identified Sorry for the print screen

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help
i need to find where each attribute is and extract its table to SQL Server, so i must find and work with tables, after knowing the structures used in specific transactions.